# Mondrian is slow and caching is low

Tags: java, performance, jvm, mondrian

### Need more Caching in Mondrian and less DB queries

Although I've enough RAM, my mondrian is really slow and does not use the RAM it should have been. The RAM is allocated as -Xmx40G in tomcat.

- I tried to explicitly use the parameters in mondrian.properties which enables caching. Like the following(although these are defaults):

mondrian.expCache.enable=true

mondrian.rolap.EnableRolapCubeMemberCache=true

mondrian.rolap.star.disableCaching=false

Still the heap usage did not increase in the visualvm.

- Then I came across this property: 
  mondrian.result.highCardChunkSize (I used 113: there is no logic behind this. I just wanted to have a big value as the default is 1 and made sure it is coprime  with the mondrian.result.limit)
  Default value: 1
  Means: When reading high cardinality dimension elements, number of elements read from database in each step. When dealing with high cardinality dimensions, elements are retrieved in blocks: first N elements are retrieved, when these elements are read, next ones (from N+1 to 2N) are got. N number is this property. Setting great values for this property increases performance but may overload memory. Values should be prime with mondrian.result.limit(I used 5000000)

source: http://mondrian.sourceforge.net/head/configuration.html

Does it really help?

I even referred to the pentaho recommendations:

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fperformance_tuning_guide%2Fconcept_mondrian_properties.html

- Any recommendations to tune the performance of Mondrian will be really helpful apart from DB tuning(indexing and all)? I fear I am missing something out here.

Answer (score 0):

My mondrian.properties is as follows:

```
# Allow the use of aggregates
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.Use=false
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.Read=false
mondrian.native.topcount.enable=true
mondrian.native.filter.enable=true
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.optimizePredicates=true
# mondrian.properties
# mondrian.result.limit=50000

# For XML/A JSPs
mondrian.test.connectString=Provider=mondrianJdbc=jdbc:odbc:MondrianFoodMart;JdbcDrivers=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver;Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml;
mondrian.result.limit=5000000

# Caching Parameters
mondrian.expCache.enable=true
mondrian.rolap.EnableRolapCubeMemberCache=true
mondrian.rolap.star.disableCaching=false
# mondrian.native.ExpandNonNative=true

mondrian.rolap.EnableRolapCubeMemberCache=true

# Default is 1000
mondrian.xmla.drillthroughMaxRows=5000

# Default is true
mondrian.util.memoryMonitor.enable=false

# Miscelleneous
# These values should be coprime to each other
mondrian.result.highCardChunkSize=113
# mondrian.query.limit=97
mondrian.rolap.maxQueryThreads=100
```